# Updating Bootstrap on Cloudformation

Tags: windows, aws-cloudformation

I am having trouble getting the update procedure to fire with cloudformation. I am following the example from http://blog.kloud.com.au/2013/08/19/bootstrap-update/. I cannot seem to get the update script to fire.

```
 "c:\\cfn\\hooks.d\\cfn-auto-reloader.conf" : {
        "content": { "Fn::Join" : ["", [
        "[cfn-auto-reloader-hook]\n",
        "triggers=post.update\n",
"path=Resources.WindowsServer.Metadata.AWS::CloudFormation::Init\n",
        "action=",
        "powershell.exe -ExecutionPolicy Bypass -NoLogo -NonInteractive -NoProfile -File c:\\cfn\\deployment\\install.ps1\n"
    ]]}
},
```

I am trying to get the powershell script to fire when the update procedure is executed, but the log is not showing anything at all, so it seem like it is not triggering.

https://s3.amazonaws.com/Sample-Aspnet-Bootstrap/windows-server.json

Comment: This is after you have modified the template, that you show no logs?

Comment: Yes, after I run thought an update the the update hook above does not seem to re run the update.

Comment: Sorry, I still don't get you 100%. You can confirm that the cfn-hup service is running and detects that a change has been made to your template, but you cannot confirm that cfn-hup executes the script at C:\cfn\deployment\install.ps1?

Comment: The cfn-update service is running, but the cfn-hup.log file is empty and my script is not running.

Comment: Thanks for all the help Edwin, your questions got me to dig deeper int he the documentation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was the update was not executing because it did not notice a change in the build. I created a simple build.txt file that held the build number. It is a little different from the example in the blog that is referenced, I created an actual file rather than just changing the metadata.
http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/cfn-hup.html

```
"AWS::CloudFormation::Init" : {
     "config" : {
        "files" : {
            "c:\\cfn\\build.txt": {
                "content" : { "Fn::Join" : ["", [
                    { "Ref" : "BuildNumber" } ]]}
             },
```